# On property of monic polynomial with integer coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-approximation

For a monic polynomial with integer coefficients $f$ where $\partial f = 2$, we have
$$
\textrm{inf}(f(x)) > 0 \implies 
\textrm{inf}(f(x)) \geq \frac{3}{4} .
$$
Could we generalize this (for common $\partial f$)?

Comment: Bounds depending of degree and height of f can be found in http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~bugeaud/travaux/Polpos1.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. If $p,q$ satisfy Pell's equation $p^2-2q^2=1$, then minimum of $f(x)=(x^2-2)^2+(qx-p)^2$ is at most $f(p/q)=1/q^4$.